# Що значить "як одуті міхи"?

Tags: вживання-слів, етимологія, значення-слів, діалекти

В коломийці "Ой заграй ми музиченьку" є такі рядки:

> Ой нездалі парубоньки як одуті міхи
>
> Лише ними доставляти до міста оріхи

Знайшов підтвердження здогадкам, що ["нездалий"](http://sum.in.ua/s/nezdalyj) - це невмілий, нездатний.

Мабуть, що ці "одуті міхи" заважають чомусь рухатися, або це ті міхи, якими піддувають вогонь, тільки я не розумію, чим вони погані в "одутому" стані.

Хтось може пояснити, що це саме, ці "одуті міхи", і звідки пішло?

Здогадуюсь, що гірське, але точної інформації знайти не можу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Міхи* – це мішки, торби. [*Одутий*](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) – це пухлий, роздутий. Вочевидь, у цій коломійці співається про гладких, товстих парубків, які такі роздуті, наче мішки, якими в місто возять горіхи.